# Why are the result keys of group-by function in order in most cases but not when using with range?

Tags: clojure

I am working on [this problem](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/56)

My solution is:

```
(fn [s]
  (map #(first %) (group-by identity s)))
```

First three tests passed and the last one failed.

Because

```
(group-by identity (range 50)
```

gives results unordered. But my solution strongly relies on the ordered feature of group-by function. That is to say the order of every key in the result map must be maintained. And this is almost true even though [the Doc](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/group-by) doesn't guarantee that.

The really weird thing is:

[image]

You see, when parameters are more than 32 group-by function gives wrong order. Results are not randomly but that the overflowed elements prepend after the first one.

Why?

How can I keep the ordered feature of group-by function or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any ordering of generic maps is an implementation detail.

Larger maps are implemented using hash tables, which will not in general preserve order. For small maps, the overhead of hashing is higher than the cost of linear lookup. So, an optimization is for small maps to begin life as an array map, which does preserve order. As more elements are added, the map is converted to a hash map.

```
(class (group-by identity (range 8)))
;=> clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

(class (group-by identity (range 32)))
;=> clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```

This conversion occurs before 32 elements, but without digging into the internals I'd suspect the initial hash table has 32 slots and so disordering does not begin to occur until the hash collision strategy kicks in.

As far as [4Clojure implement `distinct`](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/56) problem is concerned, you could salvage your solution with a `sort-by` on the `.indexOf` in the original collection.

Spoiler:

> (fn [s]
>       (sort-by #(.indexOf s %)
>         (map #(first %) (group-by identity s))))

Comment: It seems .indexOf is not allowed. (fn [s] (sort-by .indexOf (map first (group-by identity s)))). I got a "Unable to resolve symbol: .indexOf in this context" Runtime Exception.

Comment: It is a matter of how you use it -- `.indexOf` is Java interop, so in particular cannot be used as a first class function. Try wrapping inside an anonymous function and make sure it has both of its arguments.

Comment: (map first) is enough. BTW i like the spoiler.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a `sorted-map`:

```
=> (apply sorted-map (flatten (seq (group-by identity (range 50)))))
{0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 4 4, 5 5, 6 6, 7 7, 8 8, 9 9, 10 10, 11 11, 12 12, 13 13, 14 14, 15 15, 16 16, 17 17, 18 18, 19 19, 20 20, 21 21, 22 22, 23 23, 24 24, 25 25, 26 26, 27 27, 28 28, 29 29, 30 30, 31 31, 32 32, 33 33, 34 34, 35 35, 36 36, 37 37, 38 38, 39 39, 40 40, 41 41, 42 42, 43 43, 44 44, 45 45, 46 46, 47 47, 48 48, 49 49}
```

As you have seen, when you are dealing with small maps, clojure may choose an implementation that is sorted. However, this is an implementation detail and is not guaranteed. `sorted-map` returns a map for which the iteration order of keys is guaranteed to be sorted.

Comment: THanks, but what i want is not sorting them. I want the result of group-by to remain the original order.

Answer (score 0):

When adding values into a map, a collection of the appropriate type is returned.  In the case of PersistentArrayMaps, when the size becomes greater than 16 items (see the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentArrayMap.java) line 177) it returns a PersistentHashMap instead, which doesn't maintain order.

While I wasn't able to find a direct reason for the behavior to switch for the 33rd element, I know that the way Vectors are handled is in size 32 chunks so that updating one element doesn't require a completely new vector - only that chunk needs replaced.  It may have something to do with that, or some other optimization behavior.